# Parallel /parallel tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel) has at least three meanings. I propose to disambiguate them and get rid of [parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel).

- Running programs or threads in parallel, i.e. exploiting multiple cores on one computer → [parallelism](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallelism)
- [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) → [gnu-parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel)
- [Joey Hess's Parallel](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) → [moreutils-parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moreutils-parallel)

To add to the current confusion, there is a tag [parallels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallels) which is about the OSX virtualization software; I don't propose to change that tag, and the removal of `parallel` should make it stand out a bit more.

Thoughts?

Comment: Instead of getting rid completely of `/parallel`, maybe it should be kept with an excerpt suggesting the usage of those 3 tags, so that users are not tempted by it.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu If a tag isn't used on questions, it doesn't have an excerpt. But we can now display custom guidance on forbidden tags (it would [look like this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3041)), and we'll do that if we get rid of the tag.

Comment: That would be great.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds very reasonable, but I would suggest [parallelization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallelization) instead of [parallelism](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallelism). *Parallelism* can [mean many things](https://www.wordnik.com/words/parallelism):

> *from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th
> Edition*
>
> n. The quality or condition of being parallel; a parallel relationship.
>
> n. Likeness, correspondence, or similarity in aspect, course, or tendency.
>
> n. Grammar The use of identical or equivalent syntactic constructions in corresponding clauses or phrases.
>
> n. Philosophy The doctrine that to every mental change there corresponds a concomitant but causally unconnected physical
> alteration.

And I have never seen it used in the context of parallel computing (which doesn't mean it isn't used of course). *Parallelization*, on the other hand, [means](https://www.wordnik.com/words/parallelization):

> *from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License2*
>
> n. The act of making things parallel.
>
> **n. The act of making operations work in parallel, particularly in, but not limited to, computing.**

[This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parallelism%2C%20parallelization&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparallelism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparallelization%3B%2Cc0) shows a clear spike in the usage of *parallelization* just when it started becoming common in the computer world:

[image]

Finally, the Wikipedia entry for [*parallelization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelization) redirects to its page on parallel computing while its page for *parallelism* takes you to a disambiguation entry.

Comment: I'm not convinced: *parallelism* is definitely used in the context of parallel computing. *Parallelization* refers specifically to the act of implementing an algorithm in a way that takes advantage of multiple processors running in parallel. *Parallelism* refers to the study and practice of parallel computations in general (it can also mean the presence of opportunities for parallelization). The broader sense of *parallelism* is the one that's meant here.

Comment: I agree. _parallelization_ would be perfect on StackOverflow for questions about making a program parallel, and that's what your definition from the wiktionary says. In our case, in my opinion, we should be able to use this tag even for the case of _unwanted_ parallelism, i.e. race conditions. _parallelization_ would definitely not work.

Comment: @terdon well, that took a while. Ping received.

Comment: @jimsug superping deleted.