# Please blacklist the /parallel tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, blacklist-request

We've [decided to disambiguate](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/parallel-parallel-tags) the tag [parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel). We've made some headway on retagging the existing questions but it would help if there weren't new questions with the tag.

Please blacklist [parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel) and show a message:

> The “parallel” tag is not allowed. Please use either [gnu-parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel) or [parallelism](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallelism).

(Other potential tags are [moreutils-parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moreutils-parallel) and [parallel-port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel-port) but these are very rarely used.)

Comment: The tag is now devoid of questions.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Which tag? [77 questions tagged parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel)

Comment: Wow; guess I had a stale search result; sorry for the confusion. I'll continue working through them.

Comment: *now* [the parallel tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel) is devoid of questions.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yay! Thank you! Please make that an answer so we can remove this meta thread from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel) tag is now devoid of questions and is ready for blacklisting.